# change style and property onTextChange - React Native

Tags: react-native

I just began playing around with React Native and I was trying to figure out how to disable and enable a touchableOpacity when the lengths of two inputTexts are > 0.

On my touchableOpacity I have it set to disabled={true} and it has a children Text with opacity set. When a user types into the textInput's I want to set disabled={false} and change the Text opacity to 1.

```
What's the best way to do this in react native?     
Should i put ref's on them?
Should I use a className? 
setNativeProps maybe?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your constructor's state contains a flag for "isDisabled" and "textOpacity", then you can call setState in the onChangeText function that will change the state of isDisabled and textOpacity. The text component can use the opacity from the state's textOpacity and the touchableOpacity can use the state's isDisabled.

Ex:

```
`class foo extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
             isDisabled: true,
             textOpacity: 0.1,
             text1: '',
             text2: '',
         };

      onTextChange1(text) {
          if (text.length > 0 && this.state.text2.length > 0) {
              this.setState({isDisabled: false, textOpacity: 1, text1: text});
          }
          else {
              this.setState({isDisabled: true, textOpacity: 0.1, text1: text});
          }
      }

      onTextChange2(text) {
          if (text.length > 0 && this.state.text1.length > 0) {
              this.setState({isDisabled: false, textOpacity: 1, text2: text});
          }
          else {
              this.setState({isDisabled: true, textOpacity: 0.1, text2: text});
          }
      }

      render() {
          return (
              <View>
                  <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.onTextChange1(text)} value={this.state.text1}/>
                  <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => this.onTextChange2(text)} value={this.state.text2}/>
                  <TouchableOpacity disabled={this.state.isDisabled}>
                      <Text style={{opacity:this.state.textOpacity}}>Hello World!</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
          );
      }
}
```

I have not tested the above, but I believe this is basically what you are looking for. We perform a check in the on text change to see if a certain condition is met, and depending on if it is, we change the parameters of the child components as you stated. Calling setState and modifying props are the only ways to trigger a rerender, so this is how in react-native we work with rerendering components.

Comment: This worked like a charm..but im having an issue with the opacity still. The touchable opacity is disabled and when the length's are > 0 it enables it..thank you..do you think that opacity as a prop could be the issue?

Comment: What is the issue? Can you restate what you are trying to do?

Comment: The opacity just isn't setting and being affected..When the lengths are > 0  the opacity should set to 1..im surprised it isnt working since the disabled is which makes me think it has to do with the opacity property on Text..Maybe it's because I also am using a styles.varname for style on the text

Comment: My mistake, the opacity is not a prop on its on but is a part of the style prop. I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: gotcha..is there a way to combine with style={styles.varname} ? below my class i tried to do opacity: {this.state.textOpacity} in the stylesheet but error

Comment: Unfortunately not that I have found. You cannot pass this.state.textOpacity to the stylesheet since I assume that you are declaring the styles variable outside of the class, which is outside of the scope of this.state. If you wanted to combine styles you can do style={[styles.varname, {opacity: this.state.textOpacity}]}. Keep in mind that styles are just dictionaries and using StyleSheet.create is syntactic sugar and adds in some nice checking of key names to make sure that what you are assigning as values is correct/legal.

Answer (score 1):

if you want your opacity to be able to change depending on user moves, you need to set it(opacity) in state of your parent component.You can do this for example:

```
export class Parent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) { 
      super(props);
      this.state = { opacity: 0 }
   }
   render() {
      Some components ....
        <TextInput style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}} onChangeText={ () => this.setState({opacity: 1}) } ...other props here .../>
      Some components ....
   }

}
```

you can also apply other styles to your `TextInput` component.